# I am Strugling to create and understand a specific method for a simple shooter game program

Tags: java, methods, graphics

These are the specific instruction but they are kind of confusing to me (are the instructions confusing/ambiguous or am I just not getting it?)

write a method public static void draw shooter(Graphics g, Color c);
call draw shooter using the shooter color as the last parameter in drawAll(?)
test the program you should see a red disk centered near the bottom of the screen(?)

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Project2{
  public static final int PANEL_WIDTH = 300;
  public static final int PANEL_HEIGHT = 300;
  public static final int SLEEP_TIME = 50;
  public static Color SHOOTER_COLOR = Color.RED;
  public static Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
  public static final int SHOOTER_SIZE = 20; //diameter of the shooter
  public static final int GUN_SIZE = 10; //length og the gun
  public static final int SHOOTER_POSITION_Y = PANEL_HEIGHT - SHOOTER_SIZE;
  public static final int SHOOTER_INITIAL_POSITION_X = 150;
  int shooterPosition;

  public static void initialize(){
    int shooterPositionX = SHOOTER_INITIAL_POSITION_X;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT);
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics( );
    initialize();
    startGame(panel, g);
    drawShooter(g, SHOOTER_COLOR);
  }

  public static void drawShooter(Graphics g, Color C){
    g.setColor(Color);
    g.fillOval(shooterPosition, SHOOTER_POSITION_Y, SHOOTER_SIZE, SHOOTER_SIZE);
  }

  public static void drawAll(Graphics g){
    g.drawString("Project 2 by Jasmine Ramirez", 10, 15);
  }

  public static void startGame(DrawingPanel panel, Graphics g) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
      panel.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
      drawAll(g);
    }
  }
}
```

this is my code I guessed that I needed to draw and color in a circle inside the method but I am getting errors with the g.setColor inside the method and I'm not sure what the second step means. Thanks just started learning to program.

Drawing Panel

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DrawingPanel implements ActionListener {
 private static final String versionMessage = 
    "Drawing Panel version 1.1, January 25, 2015";
 private static final int DELAY = 100;  // delay between repaints in millis
 private static final boolean PRETTY = false;  // true to anti-alias
 private static boolean showStatus = false;
 private static final int MAX_KEY_BUF_SIZE = 10;

 private int width, height;    // dimensions of window frame
 private JFrame frame;         // overall window frame
 private JPanel panel;         // overall drawing surface
 private BufferedImage image;  // remembers drawing commands
 private Graphics2D g2;        // graphics context for painting
 private JLabel statusBar;     // status bar showing mouse position
 private volatile MouseEvent click;     // stores the last mouse click
 private volatile boolean pressed;      // true if the mouse is pressed
 private volatile MouseEvent move;      // stores the position of the mouse
 private ArrayList<KeyInfo> keys;

 // construct a drawing panel of given width and height enclosed in a window
 public DrawingPanel(int width, int height) {
   this.width = width;
   this.height = height;
   keys = new ArrayList<KeyInfo>();
   image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

   statusBar = new JLabel(" ");
   statusBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
   statusBar.setText(versionMessage);

   panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
   panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
   panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
   panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));

   click = null;
   move = null;
   pressed = false;

   // listen to mouse movement
   MouseInputAdapter listener = new MouseInputAdapter() {
     public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
       pressed = false;
       move = e;
       if (showStatus)
          statusBar.setText("moved (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
     }

     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
       pressed = true;
       move = e;
       if (showStatus)
          statusBar.setText("pressed (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
     }

     public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
       pressed = true;
       move = e;
       if (showStatus)
          statusBar.setText("dragged (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
     }

     public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
       click = e;
       pressed = false;
       if (showStatus)
          statusBar.setText("released (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
     }

     public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
//       System.out.println("mouse entered");
       panel.requestFocus();
     }

   };
   panel.addMouseListener(listener);
   panel.addMouseMotionListener(listener);
   new DrawingPanelKeyListener();

   g2 = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
   g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
   if (PRETTY) {
     g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
     g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.1f));
   }

   frame = new JFrame("Drawing Panel");
   frame.setResizable(false);
   try {
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // so that this works in an applet
   } catch (Exception e) {}
   frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
   frame.getContentPane().add(statusBar, "South");
   frame.pack();
   frame.setVisible(true);
   toFront();
   frame.requestFocus();

   // repaint timer so that the screen will update
   new Timer(DELAY, this).start();
 }

 public void showMouseStatus(boolean f) {
   showStatus = f;
 }

 public void addKeyListener(KeyListener listener) {
   panel.addKeyListener(listener);
   panel.requestFocus();
 }

 // used for an internal timer that keeps repainting
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   panel.repaint();
 }

 // obtain the Graphics object to draw on the panel
 public Graphics2D getGraphics() {
   return g2;
 }

 // set the background color of the drawing panel
 public void setBackground(Color c) {
   panel.setBackground(c);
 }

 // show or hide the drawing panel on the screen
 public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
   frame.setVisible(visible);
 }

 // makes the program pause for the given amount of time,
 // allowing for animation
 public void sleep(int millis) {
   panel.repaint();
   try {
     Thread.sleep(millis);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
 }

 // close the drawing panel
 public void close() {
   frame.dispose();
 }

 // makes drawing panel become the frontmost window on the screen
 public void toFront() {
   frame.toFront();
 }

 // return panel width
 public int getWidth() {
    return width;
 }

 // return panel height
 public int getHeight() {
    return height;
 }

 // return the X position of the mouse or -1
 public int getMouseX() {
   if (move == null) {
     return -1;
   } else {
     return move.getX();
   }
 }

 // return the Y position of the mouse or -1
 public int getMouseY() {
   if (move == null) {
     return -1;
   } else {
     return move.getY();
   }
 }

 // return the X position of the last click or -1
 public int getClickX() {
   if (click == null) {
     return -1;
   } else {
     return click.getX();
   }
 }

 // return the Y position of the last click or -1
 public int getClickY() {
   if (click == null) {
     return -1;
   } else {
     return click.getY();
   }
 }

 // return true if a mouse button is pressed
 public boolean mousePressed() {
   return pressed;
 }

 public synchronized int getKeyCode() {
   if (keys.size() == 0)
     return 0;
   return keys.remove(0).keyCode;
 }

  public synchronized char getKeyChar() {
   if (keys.size() == 0)
     return 0;
   return keys.remove(0).keyChar;
 }

  public synchronized int getKeysSize() {
    return keys.size();
  }

 private synchronized void insertKeyData(char c, int code) {
   keys.add(new KeyInfo(c,code));
   if (keys.size() > MAX_KEY_BUF_SIZE) {
     keys.remove(0);
//     System.out.println("Dropped key");
   }
 }

 private class KeyInfo {
   public int keyCode;
   public char keyChar;

   public KeyInfo(char keyChar, int keyCode) {
     this.keyCode = keyCode;
     this.keyChar = keyChar;
   }
 }

 private class DrawingPanelKeyListener implements KeyListener {

   int repeatCount = 0;

   public DrawingPanelKeyListener() {
     panel.addKeyListener(this);
     panel.requestFocus();
   }

   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
//     System.out.println("key pressed");
     repeatCount++;
     if ((repeatCount == 1) || (getKeysSize() < 2))
        insertKeyData(event.getKeyChar(),event.getKeyCode());
   }

   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
   }

   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
     repeatCount = 0;
   }

 }

}
```

Comment: ive changed the method to

Comment: public static void drawShooter(Graphics g, Color C){
    g.setColor(C);
    g.fillOval(SHOOTER_INITIAL_POSITION_X, SHOOTER_POSITION_Y, SHOOTER_SIZE, SHOOTER_SIZE);
  }

Comment: You can use alt + 96 to make text appear as code in comments.

Comment: Thanks. hmm I am still not getting a red Circle on the Drawing Panel Ive checked to make sure `g.fillOval()` was correct. Any suggestions

Comment: Did you change the `g.setColor(Color)` to `g.setColor(c)`?

Comment: If the problem persists, could you also add the `DrawingPanel ` class?

Comment: So I tried adding a the Drawing Panel and it still didn't work, I also simplified the method to the basics   `public static void drawShooter( ){
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(150 ,150 ,20, 20);` this showed nothing inside my program either. However i did try this exactly in a separate program with this being the only method (besides the main method) and calling it in main and it seemed to work there. Do you have any clue why this is happening?

Comment: You would have to add the `DrawingPanel` class to the question for me to tell you.

Comment: `public static void drawShooter(DrawingPanel panel, Graphics g, Color c){ g.setColor(c); g.fillOval(SHOOTER_INITIAL_POSITION_X, SHOOTER_POSITION_Y, SHOOTER_SIZE, SHOOTER_SIZE);}` and then i call it in main(? just making sure) `drawShooter(panel, g, SHOOTER_COLOR);`

Comment: I mean can you add the code for the `DrawingPanel` class, right now you have only supplied the code for the `Project 2` class. I can see you are also using the `DrawingPanel` class.

Comment: I edited my answer. It should work if follow all 3 instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1st Error

In your `drawShooter()` method you do:

> `g.setColor(Color)`

This is incorrect, since you need to pass an instance of the class Color not the class itself.

So instead use this:

```
g.setColor(C);
```

### 2nd Error

change the `shooterPosition` to `static` so that it can be accessed by a static method. 
I assume that the method `initialize()` is also wrong because you are declaring a new `shooterPosition` int for no reason so do these changes:

> `int shooterPosition;`

To:

```
public static int shooterPosition;
```

And

> `public static void initialize(){
>       int shooterPositionX = SHOOTER_INITIAL_POSITION_X;
>   }`

To:

```
public static void initialize() {
    shooterPosition = SHOOTER_INITIAL_POSITION_X;
}
```

### 3rd Error

In `startGame()` you are looping for 10000 times and each time you are waiting for a bit more than 1/20th of a second, which means that you will have to wait for almost 10 minutes until the red circle is drawn. So you have two options.

**1st option**: decrease the amount of iterations or even better remove the loop.

> `public static void startGame(DrawingPanel panel, Graphics g) {
>       for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
>           panel.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
>           drawAll(g);
>       }
>   }`

To:

```
public static void startGame(DrawingPanel panel, Graphics g) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        panel.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
        drawAll(g);
    }
}
```

or

```
public static void startGame(DrawingPanel panel, Graphics g) {
        panel.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
        drawAll(g);
}
```

**2nd option**: execute the `drawShooter()` method before the `startGame()` method or don't execute the `startGame()` at all.

> `startGame(panel, g); drawShooter(g, SHOOTER_COLOR);`

To:

```
drawShooter(g, SHOOTER_COLOR);
startGame(panel, g);
```

or

```
drawShooter(g, SHOOTER_COLOR);
```

Comment: Very nice and thorough.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks!

Comment: @ oh wow thanks that worked really well I solved problem 1 and 2 as suggested and I executed the `drawAll()` before the `startGame()` and lowered the iteration to 20 (Because I will still be needing the for loop for later). Thanks, I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you ask this same question or something similar to it yesterday? And you're passing in the class name to `g.setColor(Color)` method and need to pass in the parameter which holds the object: `g.setColor(C)`

Your use of Graphics is not good, as you shouldn't use a Graphics obtained from a component via `getGraphics()`, but I'm guessing that it's because that's what your instructor told you to do. Same for use of a `while (true)` loop. Instead you should use a Swing Timer.

Comment: Umm no. This is a school project I'm sure a ton of people are getting this around this time in CS Class.

Comment: Okay i see i included the type also with the parameter of the name instead of just the name

Comment: I don't see any questions in OP's log. I guess there are a lot of kids that are just now learning java.

Comment: Well I mean my University uses this as our second project for our first CS class. Whenever I usually try to Google help for this other university website pop up that use this in their course curriculum.

Answer (score 0):

Like stated before g.setcolor(c) is required

check your error msgs since it allows you to gather that error and the shooterPosition error(its not public so cant be used inside a method)